# NSObject default constructor

Tags: iphone, constructor, initialization, init, nsobject

The default constructor of NSObject is this?

```
-(id)init {

    return self;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly. But don't rely on this behavior.

Comment: thanks! 
so the best way is create a own costructor that inside call 
[self init];